# How would I validate digital signature for PDFs in linux?

Tags: linux, pdf

Adobe Reader, which I use on MS Windows, has the ability to validate the digital signature (created with an X.509 certificate) in a PDF file.

I'd like to do such verification on Linux desktops. I've tried Evince and Okular, the most recommended PDF readers, but they can't do that.
On the other hand, Adobe Reader is not available for Linux (see https://get.adobe.com/reader/otherversions/). PDF readers that are built-in in current versions of Firefox and Chrome neither can verify the signatures.

I'm fine with using a gui, command line tool or a firefox/chrome extension to do this.

Comment: Take a look: http://askubuntu.com/questions/226257/how-can-i-validate-a-pdfs-digital-signature-with-evince

Comment: I've found out that recently there has been some development in [poppler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poppler_%28software%29), the PDF lib used by Envice and Okular, - see  [Bug 16770 - support for digital signatures](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=16770).

Answer (score 36):

Poppler (poppler-utils) contains `pdfsig`, which verifies the signature against the stored known certificates.

It's not yet super advanced (no export), but a great step ahead.

**UPDATE**: The original bug number is [16770](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=16770) and it was pushed into production on 2016-03-01; it was included first in **v0.42**.

Comment: It would be great if you can [edit] this answer to tell us which version (even approximately) introduced this.

Comment: Is this imported in Okular or Eviance?

Comment: Not available in the poppler-utils included with Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @s1d: it was first in Bionic Beaver, whatever that means in Ubuntuland. I guess 16.04 is old.

Answer (score 30):

Libreoffice Draw is able to read PDFs and allows one to verify document's certificate and signature (`File -> Digital Signatures -> Digital Signatures…`).

Also, when the PDF has been loaded, there is a warning message if the certificate could not be validated, yet the signature was OK.

I've tested it using 6.0.4.2, but according to [crowdfunding page related to PDF signatures in LibreOffice](http://wilhelmtux.ch/?MID=11&PID=92) it probably was possible back in 2015, in versions 4.4 or 4.5.

Comment: Not working for me, says not able to open encrypted document even after supplying the password. v5.1 on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @s1d was that encrypted document signed as well?

Comment: Yes, same eAadhar document being talked about in other threads on this page.

Comment: Using fedora, LibreOffice Draw does not show any sign of a digital signature for one [sample signed PDF](https://kbdeveloper.qoppa.com/wp-content/uploads/blank_signed.pdf), [and another](https://www.tecxoft.com/samples/pdf_digital_signature_timestamp.pdf).

Answer (score 8):

with either:

- LibreOffice Draw
- [Okular since KDE Applications 19.04.0](https://pointieststick.com/2019/01/13/this-week-in-usability-productivity-part-53/)
- [Evince does not support that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226257/how-can-i-validate-a-pdfs-digital-signature-with-evince), but there is an unofficial patch
- `pdfsig` (from `poppler-utils`, req. the root cert. installed in your Firefox profile dir)

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: i've noticed the question was a duplicate AFTER answering, so i've deleted my answer and reposted on the older one after flagging as a duplicate.

Comment: Perfect. Well done.

Comment: Libreoffice 7 Draw does not seem to recognise signatures on Fedora 38 today.

Answer (score 3):

Try our software [PDF Studio Viewer](https://www.qoppa.com/pdfstudioviewer), a PDF Reader for Linux that supports rendering and validating digital signatures. I am a developer for this software.

Disclosure: I am a developer at Qoppa

Comment: I tried it, it is actually very simple to check whether a pdf is signed or not. I don't know why this was downvoted.

Comment: I tried this. Got "Signature not validated" message at the bottom of the document. When I click on the question mark hovering that message, I get a "Signature validity is UNKNOWN" pop-up. When I further click on "Details" button, I get certificate details and a button "Trust Certificate" which I click on. I then restart the PDF Studio Viewer and re-open the file, and I still get the same "Signature not validated" message with the question mark, and still "Signature validity is UNKNOWN" when I click on the mark. However, once I click on "Details", it tells me that the certificate is trusted. :S

Answer (score -2):

The following steps show how to download the Aadhaar Card and convert it to a nice PDF:

1. Goto https://eaadhaar.uidai.gov.in/eaadhaar/ and fill this ugly looking form.
2. Enter the code from the SMS to download and save the file. I assume you saved it as “aadhaar-unverified.pdf”.
3. Install acrobat reader and javascript plugins from the deb-multimedia.org repository: apt-get install acroread acroread-plugins acroread-escript
4. Open the file with acroread, the password is the ZIP of the city.
5. Click on the question mark, a window with title “Signature Validation Status” opens.
6. Click “Signature Properties” to open the window with the same title.
7. Click “Show Certificate” to open the certificate window.
   Choose the “Trust” tab.
8. Click “Add to Trusted Identities”.
9. Click “OK” to close the certificate window.
10. Click “Validate Signature”.
11. Click “Close” to close the Signature Properties window.
12. Print the page into the file “aadhaar-verified.ps”.
13. Convert the postscript file to pdf. The following command is one line. The “sed” removes a stupid “copy protection” from the postscript file and ps2pdf then creates the PDF file.
    `sed "/mark currentfile eexec/,/cleartomark/ d" aadhaar-verified.ps | ps2pdf - aadhaar-verified.pdf`
14. Now print the copy of your E-Aadhaar Card on paper and make backups of your PDF file.

Now you have a nice verified PDF which you can print without any problems. Wasn’t that simple, eh?

Comment: Can you please elaborate step no.3 ?

Comment: I so much don't understand what is this all about that I can't even downvote.

Comment: I am glad these morons specifically designed the aadhar verification process to irritate linux users.I wonder how the code on backend would be.